# Can anybody help me with this? I am just a beginner

Tags: sql

```
Select 
    m.style_id,
    sum(p.production_qty) Cutting 
From 
    Master_Data m 
Left Join 
    production_data p on P.Style_ID = M.Style_ID 
where 
    p.production_process = 'Cutting', 

    sum(p.production_qty) Induction 
From 
    Master_Data m 
Left Join 
    production_data p on P.Style_ID = M.Style_ID 
where 
    p.production_process = 'Induction', 
group by 
    m.style_id
```

How to get result of two different select statements?

Comment: You should provide sample data and desired results.  And you should tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional aggregation to get the result you want:

```
Select 
    m.style_id,
    sum(case when p.production_process = 'Cutting' then p.production_qty else 0 end) Cutting 
    sum(case when p.production_process = 'Induction' then p.production_qty else 0 end) Induction 
From 
    Master_Data m 
Left Join 
    production_data p on P.Style_ID = M.Style_ID 
where 
    p.production_process in ('Induction', 'Cutting')
group by 
    m.style_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want the result set to look like, you can use aggregation:

```
Select p.production_process, m.style_id,
       sum(p.production_qty) Cutting 
From Master_Data m left join 
     production_data p
     on p.Style_ID = m.Style_ID and
        p.production_process in ('Cutting', 'Induction')
group by p.production_process, m.style_id;
```